# Microsoft ergonomic keyboard 4000 v10 key bounce issues

Tags: keyboard

I've used a Microsoft ergonomic keyboard 4000 v10  for a few years, but the issue of key bounce with repeating deletes has become much worse since going to windows 7 64 bit professional.

"Key bounce" traditionally refers to the situation where you hit a single key but the action is repeated one one or more times. For example, I highlight a single e-mail and hit the DEL key. The result is that that E-mail is deleted together with the next 1-3 E-mails.

This plagued early keyboards, but has not been a problem in that last couple of decades.

What makes it more annoying is that it also occurs when I highlight an E-mail and use the mouse to click on the DELETE symbol in the ribbon.

As noted, I have already investigated the Tool Tips issue.

Can you explain why this is happening and how i would fix it?

Comment: Your question seems to start in the middle of something. What exactly are you asking us to explain?

Comment: Does this problem occur on the same USB port? Have you tried a different keyboard and mouse? Can you reproduce it using a USB hub?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its a software issue (and it getting worse due to switching OS indicates its a possibility), have you tried adjusting your repeat delay and repeat rate in control panel?

[image]